# PrintVisual won't print unless run as Administrator

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2015

I currently have a WPF C# application that basically loads a XAML Window control, stuff information in it, and then call PrintVisual();

On Windows 10, this operation works normally for standard user (Limited permission). However on Windows 7, PrintVisual hangs and does not print unless application is elevate to run as Administrator.

All windows 7 machine has been updated to the latest version.

Here's my question; why does PrintVisual require administrator privilege to print? Do I need to use a different technique when running on Windows 7?

*(Thought about Graphic.CopyFromScreen Method to bypass administrative privilege...)*

Below is a code sniplet of where the problem lies.

```
BinLocation bl = new BinLocation();   // A Windows control object
PrintDialog dlg = new PrintDialog();  // API from System.Windows.Controls
LocalPrintServer prtSrv = new LocalPrintServer();  // API from System.Printing
PrintQueue pq = prtSrv.GetPrintQueues(new[] { EnumeratedPrintQueueTypes.Local }).Where(w => w.Name.Contains("QL-500") && !w.IsOffline).FirstOrDefault();
if (pq != null) dlg.PrintQueue = pq;
bl.Show();
// Problem here with Win7 Standard user, code hangs and refuse to raise exception. using System.Windows.Media.Visual
dlg.PrintVisual(bl, "");
bl.Close();
```

I am currently using WPF C# project in VS2015 on Win7 x64 machine.